# Finite good covers on smooth manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, cw-complexes

Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold that is not necessarily compact but has the homotopy type of a finite CW complex.

> Does $M$ admit a **finite good cover**? (i.e. a finite cover by contractible opens whose multiple intersections are also contractible)

I expect the answer to be yes, but I don’t see an argument as of now.

Comment: Do you really need contractible opens, or do you accept open sets that are disjoint unions of contractibles?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Let’s say $M$ is connected. But yes I would content myself of a cover made my opens that are **finite** disjoint unions of contractibles, all whose multiple intersections are also finite disjoint unions of contractibles.

Comment: Tom's answer here seems pretty close to giving a counter-example to what you want: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48505/finite-type-vs-finite-dimensional-cohomology